# CentOS 7 lost data when power off

Tags: centos7, svn

I have an issue. So I don't know why.

My server is CentOS 7. I installed Subversion server on it.

Last week my server has error when Power Off.
After server restart. Newest SVN's data was lost. Only display old data (last 1 year's data).

I dont know why. How to recovery newest data.

Please help.

Comment: What file system were you using? When was the last time the system was restarted prior to this? Was it last restarted a year ago?

Comment: Also, I know this is not helpful if you do not have them, but if you do have them now is the time to start restoring from backups

Comment: >What file system were you using
I don't know it. Last restarted 3 months ago.
I've just checked. Not only SVN -> All system file (Centos). It seems Centos recover automatically. But in my server, I havent got backup partition. It's so funny.

Answer (score 1):

Considering hiring professional Subversion support. Developer level experience with the repository structure may help in recovery.

I don't have those steps to recover, but for a start do not work on the only copy of your data.

- Image the disk containing the SVN repo
- Identify any backups you may have
- Find the most recent checked out working copy and back that up too